# Google Sheets Script permissions for everyone allowed access to a sheet

Tags: google-sheets, authorization, user-permissions, google-apps-script-editor

I know there are a lot of questions out there related to Google Scripts and some of them touch on my issue but I can't seem to figure out the full answer.

I only want to be able to run 1 or 2 scripts in the same project file for 1 spreadsheet. How do I allow permission for everyone with whom the sheet is shared WITHOUT forcing each user to go through the process of allowing Authorization? Is this possible?

Maybe there is an alternative script? Here is my script (in case this helps):

```
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{name:"Go to active row", functionName:"Go to active 
row"}];
  sheet.addMenu("Scripts", entries);
myFunction();
};

function gotoend() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    var lastRow = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

lastRow.forEach(function (row,index) {
    if (row[3] == "") {  // row[0] is the same as Column A. row[1] = B
        lastRow.length = index;
    }
});

var newRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow.length,1);
sheet.setActiveRange(newRange);
}
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */
```

Comment: If a person wants to use code that modifies spreadsheets on their behalf, they must grant permission to it. Apps Script does not do provisional access elevation, instead it requests permission for the most dangerous scopes defined anywhere in the project, even if they are not called by the functions that will be used (and even if they are commented out). By including `@OnlyCurrentDoc` you are doing what you can.

Comment: Bummer. I thought that's how things seemed but couldn't confirm. Thanks for the clarification