# Google scripts in google sheets, is permission for all users?

Tags: google-apps-script, permissions

I've written a tiny script/ macro in google sheets when an image is clicked, some boxes in cells get unticked, when I first used clicked it myself, I had to give permission for myself.

My question is, the other user that I share these sheets with, will they now have permission automatic permission?

I ask because they are not computer literate and won't be able to grant themselves permission.

Comment: If they don’t authorize the script then won’t be able to use it. This is for their protection no way around it.

Comment: Okay, thank you, makes sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49536462/google-sheets-script-permissions-for-everyone-allowed-access-to-a-sheet

Answer (score 1):

Apps Script scans the code automatically and determines which are the authorization scopes. In this case, all users you share the spreadsheet with will have to grant explicit permission for the script to modify the file on their behalf. This cannot be avoided.

Check this out for more information: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization